# Image from computer isn't uploading using html

Tags: html

I'm having trouble uploading an image (google logo) I have saved onto my mac using html/css. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My html file is saved in a folder titled google-homepage, within that page is a folder called CSS, within there is a folder named images, and in that folder is my image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> "Google" </title>
<body>
<img src="css/images/google.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- create folder name: **google-homepage**

2- inside **google-homepage** create file name index.html , past the code bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> "Google" </title>
<body>
<center>
<img src="CSS/images/google.png"/>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

3- create folder inside **google-homepage** name **CSS**

4- create folder name **images** inside folder **CSS**  and copy your image with name 'google.png'

5- now run on IE the file name index.html

good luck

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly! I guess my problem was not having the css in uppercase. Thank you!

Comment: may i i think it's because of the directory when you want to reference as (src) you must be very careful directory addressing. PLEASE UP VOTE thank you

Comment: Hey I tried but unfortunately it says if I have less than 15 reputation I can't :( I'll make sure I upvote once Im at 15!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<img src="../css/images/google.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if your image is not corrupted. Also check where is your HTML file located? 
If everything is fine check with the following code.

```
<img src = "./CSS/images/google.png">
```

Also check for directory name. Don't mix uppercase with lowercase. Hope that solves!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<img src="file:///css/images/google.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <title>Google</title>
    <body>
         <img src="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\CSS\images\a.jpg" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Try to give the full path using **directory path**.
Hope it will help you